# Open file has data but reports back length 0 in python

Tags: python, csv

I must be missing something very simple here, but I've been hitting my head against the wall for a while and don't understand where the error is. I am trying to open a csv file and read the data. I am detecting the delimiter, then reading in the data with this code:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read())
    delimiter = repr(dialect.delimiter)[1:-1]
    csvdata = [line.split(delimiter) for line in csvfile.readlines()]
```

However, my csvfile is being read as having no length. If I run:

```
print(sum(1 for line in csvfile))
```

The result is zero. If I run:

```
print(sum(1 for line in open(filepath, 'r')))
```

Then I get five lines, as expected. I've checked for name clashes by changing csvfile to other random names, but this does not change the result. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: You exhausted your file ierator. It's only good for a single pass.

Comment: Also, don't use the `repr` of the delimeter of the dialect object returned by the sniffer... *It's already what you want it to be*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the file pointer back to the start of the file after sniffing it. You don't need to read the whole file in to do that, just enough to include a few rows:

```
import csv

with open(filepath, 'r') as f_input:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f_input.read(2048))
    f_input.seek(0)
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, dialect)
    csv_data = list(csv_input)
```

Also, the `csv.reader()` will do the splitting for you.